# In circular motion why is the vector $\mathbf v_f$ minus the vector $\mathbf v_i$ equal to the vector $\Delta \mathbf v$?

Tags: kinematics, vectors

What is the vector $\Delta \mathbf v$ ? and why does equal $\mathbf v_2 - \mathbf v_1$.

notice: I knew about calculus, my question is not generally but it is about circular figure, vectores confused me .

Briefly what is $\Delta \mathbf v$ in this picture .

Thank you all .
[image: test]

Comment: As your diagram shows, $\Delta \mathbf v$ is the change in velocity from time $t$ to time $t+\Delta t$. What is confusing you about this?

Comment: Ok, I want to understand How Δv represented in the circle in circular motion, please look the the picture https://i.ibb.co/Tkh2fSL/imageedit-4-5275615930.png , is right vector Δv = vector a + vector b ?

Comment: That picture isn't very clear. I think your vectors a & b are those little purple vectors pointing towards the circle, but it isn't clear *exactly* what direction they point. And I don't understand why you want to add a & b. $\Delta \mathbf v$ is a *difference*, not a sum. The diagram here in your question shows exactly what the direction & magnitude of $\Delta \mathbf v$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Just see the fact in vector figure it just the direction and the magnitude of vector that does matters , So you can move the vector all around the space. So what they did is  move the tail of vector $\mathbf{v}(t+\Delta t)$ to tail of vector $\mathbf{v}(t)$ that give you the small figure on the right.Now they use the vector addition $$\mathbf{v}(t)+\Delta\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}(t+\Delta t)$$
$$\Delta\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}(t+\Delta t)-\mathbf{v}(t)$$

Comment: but i have a doubt in this rule, i told before without vectors i can understand, but vectors make me confused, now my question is why Δv equals v(t+Δt)−v(t) .

Answer (score 1):

Because it's vector algebra rule for vector subtraction $\vec{v}_\Delta = \vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1$. This speed vector always points to the same direction centripetal acceleration points to. If you normalize this speed difference vector over time elapsed - you will get centripetal acceleration. A bit more clear picture :
[image]

Comment: I want to bind this rule with my Intuition but I still I can not understand why is the arrow Dv represents the difference between vector Vf and Vector Vi, without vectors i understand but with them i can't, please help me and explain it to me in depth .

Answer (score 0):

Delta v is just an abbreviation for v2-v1 so it is the little green vector in your picture

Comment: Yes, i saw the little green vector, but what does represent in the circular ?

Comment: to see the difference of two vectors you have to put them on the same point , this is done in the picture with the to vectors on the circle, they are just moved but still the same vectors,

Comment: But what does mean the difference of two vectors in circular ? i knew in normal calculus  Vf - Vi = Dv, Dv may be an acceleration if Dt is 1, but in our example what is Dv ? .

Comment: @BadGuy $\Delta(v)$ always shows the direction of the acceleration. Theres no such thing as "difference of two vectors in circular". What do you mean by circular ? You are just subtracting two vectors theres nothing more.

Comment: Please look to this picture to understand my intention https://i.ibb.co/Tkh2fSL/imageedit-4-5275615930.png

Comment: am i right in the picture ?? Vector Dv = vector a + vector b

Comment: no Dv is not a+b, in the picture a is about Dv. the acceleration is Dv/Dt not Dv. the acceleration here does not change the absolute value of v it changes only the direction. Dv is in the direction of the radius when it gets small enough i.e, perpendicular to v, the best explanation is in the picture of Agnius Vasiliauskas